# post xml as a binary file using javascript

Tags: javascript, xml, ajax, yui

I'm trying to write something that can post xml, as a binary file to an external URL (which I have no control over) in JavaScript.
I have YUI3 available to me. And probably jQuery if I needed it.

Any ideas? Everything I've looked at seems to be about receiving xml, rather than posting it.

**Edit**: The external url is an advertising bot, the xml essentially describes what sort of ad I want to get back.

I'm forced to post as binary. I've tested using-

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="http://something.com" method="post">
<input name="anything" type="file">something</file>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

and that works. I just need to implement in js.
**Edit #2**

My solution (couldn't get it formatted properly)-

`var AdManager = {
    getRandomBoundary : function(){
        var today = new Date;
        return '---' + today.getTime();
    },
    fetch : function(){
        var boundary = this.getRandomBoundary();
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest;
        var CRLF  = "\r\n";`

```
    xhr.open('POST', 'http://url.com', true);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if (xhr.readyState === 4)
        {
            //Parse xml(badly)
            var splitter = xhr.responseText.split('<responsecontent>');
            var allAds = '';
            for (var i= 1; i< splitter.length; i++)
            {
                var tempAd = splitter[i].split('</responsecontent>');
                allAds += tempAd[0];
            }
            //Html is returned encoded, so decode.
            jQuery('#results').html(jQuery("<div/>").html(allAds).text());
        }
    };

    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data; boundary=' + boundary);

    var mimeReq = "--" + boundary + CRLF;
    mimeReq += 'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="arbitrary"; filename="arbitrary.xml"' + CRLF;
    mimeReq += 'Content-Type: application/octet-stream' + CRLF + CRLF;
    mimeReq += '<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?><adrequestpacket responsemarkup=\"wml\" test=\"0\" xmlns=...'+ CRLF;
    mimeReq += "--" + boundary + "--" + CRLF;

    xhr.send(mimeReq);
}
```

};
`

Comment: looks to me you are trying to XSS, if not ... how do you know for sure that "external URL" will post your XML if you don't have any control over it ?

Comment: what's the purpose of posting XML as binary, are you trying to preserve endianness even though the target computer doesn't have the same? Why not just posting XML as XML, as in a normal HTTP POST?

Comment: I've edited the question, hopefully that clarifies both your comments.

Comment: After your edit it becomes clearer. And it also becomes clear why it doesn't work: input of type `file` takes a file from a local disk. It's security preventing you from sending this through JavaScript, otherwise any page could send any file from your computer over the internet without user intervention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I understand what your asking, but if I'm totally on the wrong track, the below may appear a little patronising, so apologies in advance...

If all you want to do is send an XML file to a known URL via AJAX its fairly simple in javascript with no lovelies like jQuery etc. I am assuming you have already generated the XML file and have it stored as string variable somewhere.

The below code is a bit messy and fairly basic, but hopefully it should point you in the right direction. There are probably better ways of fetching an AJAX object if you search for them, but this is a method I have used for ages and never really have any problems with.

You will need to write some code to parse the server response to determine whether data was accepted or not - see comments in code for where you would do this. The `ajaxObj.status` and `ajaxObj.responseText` properties will be your friends here.

```
function postXMLToServer (serverURL, xmlStr) {

  // Declare some variables
  var activeXModes, i, ajaxObj, aSync, contentType;

  // Set this to false to perform the request synchronously (i.e. execution will block until request has completed)
  aSync = true;

  // 'application/octet-stream' is treated as raw binary data by any sensible server.
  // It might make more sense to use 'text/xml' or some variant depending on your application
  contentType = 'application/octet-stream';

  // Fetch an AJAX object
  activeXModes = ["Msxml2.XMLHTTP","Microsoft.XMLHTTP"];
  if (window.ActiveXObject) { // Try ActiveX (for IE)
    for (i = 0; i < activeXModes.length; i++) {
      try {
        ajaxObj = new ActiveXObject(activeXModes[i]);
      } catch (e) {}
    }
  } else if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // For Mozilla, Safari etc
    ajaxObj = new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else { // No AJAX
    alert('AJAX is not supported in your browser');
    return;
  }

  // Open connection to server
  ajaxObj.open('POST',serverURL,aSync);

  // Set some request headers - you might be able to get away with not doing this, but it
  // should be considered good practice, especially when doing POST requests
  ajaxObj.setRequestHeader('Content-Type',contentType);
  ajaxObj.setRequestHeader('Content-Length',xmlStr.length);

  // Set a callback for asynchronous requests (not called if aSync = false)
  ajaxObj.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (ajaxObj.readyState == 4) {

      // parse the server response here

    }
  };

  // Send the request
  ajaxObj.send(xmlStr);

  // if aSync = false, parse the server response here

}

// Example of how to use the function
var myXMLStr = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1" ?>\n<toplevel>\n<lowerlevel anattribute="a value">An inner value</lowerlevel>\n</toplevel>';
var myURL = 'http://sub.domain.tld/path/to/document.ext?getparameter=somevalue';

postXMLToServer(myURL,myXMLStr);
```

Comment: Thanks, but the problem is getting the xml posted in a binary format, not that I can't do an ajax call.

Comment: Reading your edit, what you need to do is set the contentType variable above to `multipart/form-data; boundary="--ThisIsMyBoundaryStringThatWillNeverAppearInMyContent"` and wrap your XML into a [multipart MIME format message](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME#Multipart_messages).

Comment: Excellent, thankyou. This comment led me to this article - http://igstan.ro/posts/2009-01-11-ajax-file-upload-with-pure-javascript.html which was exactly what I wanted.

Comment: DaveRandom, it's probably more performance-efficient to test the `XMLHttpRequest` branch first, as most browsers, including IE from version 8 up, support it.

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear what you want. **Everything** in the computer is represented in binary. So when you post an XML document over to `http://something.com`, the it's the binary representation of the characters in the XML file that is being transmitted.

Comment: While it's true that everything is essentially binary, XML and other text-based formats are often converted while transferred. Either from big endian to little endian, or from CRLF line endings to LF or CR line endings. However, when sending using an HTTP POST request, normally such translation does not happen if done with a browser and what you receive is equal to what you send (while on the wire it's a different representation though).